# Ubuntu 14.04 subshell and variable expansion in custom keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

How can I enable bash expansion by custom keyboard shortcuts in 14.04? Here's an example that I've been trying to get setup; I want to execute this exact command (which works from a terminal running bash):

```
gnome-screenshot --window --remove-border -f ~/Pictures/screenshot_$(date +%x_%H:%M:%S:%N).png
```

It doesn't work as is, and neither does:

```
gnome-screenshot --window --remove-border -f $HOME/Pictures/screenshot_$(date +%x_%H:%M:%S:%N).png
```

If I change it to the following:

```
gnome-screenshot --window --remove-border -f "/home/user/Pictures/screenshot_$(date +%x_%H:%M:%S:%N).png"
```

I end up with a file on my desktop called "screenshot_$(date +%x_%H:%M:%S:%N).png" (no subshell expansion). What am I doing wrong? What executes these commands if not bash? Why aren't the subshells or variables/tildes expanded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyboard shortcuts field in Unity works in a similar manner to `.desktop` files, i.e. commands are executed without any form of subshell or variable expansion and can't access any environment variables.

I wasn't able to find an official specification regarding the keyboard shortcuts menu but I think it's save to assume that command execution follows similar guidelines to the [Exec field](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html) in XDG `.desktop` files.

What this means, in practice, is that there are two ways you can make your custom command-line work with the shortcuts menu:

1. **Transform your commands into a simple shell script and point the keyboard shortcut to the shell script.**

   For instance, you could paste the following into a new text file, name it something like `custom_screenshot_script` and make the script executable:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   gnome-screenshot --window --remove-border -f "~/Pictures/screenshot_$(date +%x_%H:%M:%S:%N).png"
   ```
2. **Call `bash` to execute your command.**

   This is more tricky because you have to escape your arguments correctly. Something like the following should work:

   ```bash
   bash -c "gnome-screenshot --window --remove-border -f \"~/Pictures/screenshot_$(date +%x_%H:%M:%S:%N).png\""
   ```

Answer (score -2):

In my case I would make a script:

## /bin/sh

Case (window_border) in
        ~./picture

```
    gnome-screenshot --window ~/picture/screenshot_$(date+%X_% H:$M:$:$S:$n)*png

    Bash -i remove-border -f window

    Bash --window --remove-border -f ''~/picture/screenshot_$(date+%X_%H:$M:$:$S:$N).png''
```

endl

and it might work Fine This Way.